# column ambigously defined

Tags: sql, oracle

```sql
with t1 as (
  SELECT *
  from   claim fc
         inner join drug_product d
         on d.drug_id = d.drug_id 
            AND d.id = d.id
         inner join pharmacy pha
         on fc.pharmacy_id = pha.pharmacy_id
            and fcnum = pha.num
),
t2 as (
  Select d_memberid,
         fill_dt,
         num,
         d_drug_id,
         count(distinct device_type) as device_count,
         count(device_type),
         count(distinct claim_ID)as claim_count
  from   t1
  group by
         d_member_id,
         fill_dt,
         num
)
Select   t1.*,
         t2.device_count,
         d.* 
from     t1 
         inner join t2 
         on t1.num = t2.num 
            and t1.fill_dt = t2.fill_dt 
            and t1.d_member_id = t2.d_member_id
         inner join drug_product d 
            on t1.d_drug_id = d.d_drug_id
order by claim_count desc
```

**column ambiguouly defined.  Im trying to find if there dup drug fill on the same day. line 54 column 32**
column ambigously defined.  I wonder if my joins are incorrect. for t1 i join 3 different table for t2 is from the first table. outcome should be a join of the t1 and t2

Comment: What happens if you run the `t1` subquery on its own? Then what happens if you run the `t1` and `t2` subqueries without the final query? What happens if you run it all without the final `ORDER BY` statement? What happens if you run it all without the joining the `d` table in the final step? ... What have **YOU** tried to debug this yourself?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [MRE] with the `CREATE TABLE` statements for all the tables you are referencing. If we cannot recreate your setup then we can only guess where the problem can be; so help us to help you and give us a complete question that contains all the information necessary to provide you an answer.

Comment: what table is f_skey_hicl_cd associated with.

Comment: same with and d_member_hq_id?  Which table source

Comment: from table md_claim

Answer (score 1):

`d_member_hq_id` is not prefixed by a table alias, and could be causing the problem if the column name exists in more than 1 table in the from clause. There are other columns which are also not qualified, it is a good practice to qualify all columns to avoid this error.

Comment: what do you mean by columns not qualified?

Comment: In `select d.drug_id` is `drug_id` is explicitely defined as coming from the table with alias `d` (the column reference is qualified with a table name or alias).  In `select drug_id` , the column is not qualified. As long as there is one table in the `from` clause that has that name, no problem. But if there is more than on table with a column `drug_id` then you get the column ambiguously defined error, because the SQL is not going to guess which table's drug_id column you want to select. The same applies to columns in `where` clauses.